# If statements & else not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    if b1a == "rock":
    print("you gave him a concussion and made the rock your new weapon")
    weapon = "rock"
else:
    print("you had a heart attack because you didn't pick one of the options")
    exit()

if b1a == "NIGERUNDAYO":
    weapon = "tommy gun"
    print("You ran so much that the beast got tired, then you took out a tommy gun and started shooting")
else:
    print("you had a heart attack because you didn't pick one of the options")
    exit()

if b1a == "slash":
    print("you slashed his face with a hatchet. ")
else:
    print("you had a heart attack because you didn't pick one of the options")
    exit()
```

It always gives me the heart attack.

I am a beginner and want to know if there is another way to go about this.

Comment: You need `elif`.

Comment: If you are a beginner, then reading some basic tutorials about Python might be a very good idea in this case. The problem you seem to have should be covered by them and many other helpful things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to just use `elif` each time instead of `if-else` construction.

```
if b1a == "rock":
    print("you gave him a concussion and made the rock your new weapon")
    weapon = "rock"
elif b1a == "NIGERUNDAYO":
    weapon = "tommy gun"
    print("You ran so much that the beast got tired, then you took out a tommy gun and started shooting") 
elif b1a == "slash":
    print("you slashed his face with a hatchet. ")
else:
    print("you had a heart attack because you didn't pick one of the options")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solution may suffice.

Try [elif statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm).

```
if b1a == "rock":
    print("you gave him a concussion and made the rock your new weapon")
    weapon = "rock"

elif b1a == "NIGERUNDAYO":
    weapon = "tommy gun"
    print("You ran so much that the beast got tired, then you took out a tommy gun and started shooting")
    exit()

elif b1a == "slash":
    print("you slashed his face with a hatchet. ")

else:
     print("you had a heart attack because you didn't pick one of the options")
     exit()
```